# Unit test performance gap between IDE and maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, unit-testing, junit

Working in eclipse, I have a project that contains 221 unit test classes,
where methods are annotated with @Test (org.junit.Test).

When I right-click the project and click "Run As -> JUnit Test", it completes within 3-5 seconds.

When the same tests are run via maven command ("mvn test"), it takes about 50 seconds.

Considering I have about 50 such projects, it makes the test run for the entire system take a quiet a long time.

I would like to run **all unit tests and only the tests** (considering everything is already compiled and built).
Anyone knows a possible optimization to the maven command?

Comment: a. You may try increasing the memory allocated to maven for test.https://bodez.wordpress.com/resources/maven-tips-tricks/unit-testing-jvm-memory-settings/  . b. Identify if time spent on server is higher, in that case, try to execute tests when server load is low.

Comment: @akshayapandey : I don't believe that increasing memory will have any performance benefit unless OS do swapping. Increasing memory is necessary is tests itself needs bigger heap ten is provided by default.

Comment: He specifically asked for possible optimizations to maven command, hence pointed to that.

Comment: *"I would like to run all unit tests and only the tests (considering everything is already compiled and built). Anyone knows a possible optimization to the maven command?"* - yes, keep using the IDE which provides this useful feature :/ Maven is never going to be fast, it is designed to be used infrequently to do the bulk packaging work at the end of a development pipeline.

Comment: Where exactly is the time spent?

Comment: How many tests are running via command line in Maven? Number? and how many tests have run from within the IDE? The same number? I would take a look how many tests have run and how long the tests take...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no optimization needed.

If you look at the Maven output, it's doing more than just running your tests.  It's performing all the steps that precede 'test' in the Maven lifecycle: compile, package, etc.

I'll assume that you're using Maven in your continuous integration pipeline.  50 seconds is not a deal breaker.  Your developers will soon learn that they should run the tests in the IDE, commit their working code, and then let the pipeline use Maven to prepare the code for the environment.

I know a 10X increase in time is shocking, but in the larger scheme of things it's not worth worrying about.  You've got far bigger inefficiencies in your development cycle to address.